# Displaying simple data with Chartkick.js in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I want to display data using chartkick in rails. 
My data structure is very simple.

```
    //Table Drinks
    Created_at   Water (in l)    Beer (in l)   Coffee (in l)
    21/02/2016      1                2              1
    20/02/2016      2                1              0
    19/02/2016      2                2              2
    ...
```

I want to draw three line charts. Each line chart should show the days on the x-axis and the amount of liters on the y-axis (one chart for each kind of drink).

I am just too confused to figure out how to do the right queries.

```
    <%= line_chart ?????????? %>
```

Here is the link to the chartkick github repo: https://github.com/ankane/chartkick

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)  ActiveRecord function to pluck out data from table in an array. [Chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick) supports [array](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick#data) as input so it should work fine.

Ex:

```
<%= line_chart
{name: "Water", data: Drink.pluck(:created_at,:water)}
{name: "Beer", data: Drink.pluck(:created_at,:beer)}
{name: "Coffee", data: Drink.pluck(:created_at,:coffee)}
 %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code doesn't work. Could you post a solution by using collect/map without pluck?